# LaTeX Style Formating for Undergraduate Papers

Tags: formatting, format-files

I was wondering what the best LaTeX style formatting is for writing an undergraduate paper? I have only used it for lab reports so far and need to expand my knowledge of formatting for different uses.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: If there's no specific guidelines from your institution, then I suppose any style for articles would be okay, including those for lab reports.

Comment: You really need to narrow your question, as it is really broad as it stands.

Comment: Depending on your field of study(?), your professor/instructor will quite likely adhere to the (subconscious) philosophy that computer-written papers should still look like they were written with a typewriter: 1" margins, double-spaced, 12-point font. (These are easily achieved via, e.g., `setspace.sty` and `geometry.sty`.) Some will be more flexible, however.  Why not ask?